# Adding identity to existing .NET Core project , in web layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-identity

In web layer I have 2 classes in the `identity` folder

```
public class ApplicationIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

My startup is :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddScoped<IProductDal, EfCoreProductDal>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductManager>();
        services.AddScoped<ICategoryDal, EfCoreCategoryDal>();
        services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryManager>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_0);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            SeedDatabase.Seed();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
       
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name:"adminProducts",
                pattern:"admin/products",
                defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "ProductList" });
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "adminProducts",
                pattern: "admin/products/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "EditProduct" });
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "products",
                pattern: "products/{category?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Shop", action = "List" });
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
    }
}
```

Although everthing seems okay, when I am trying to create migration on the command line in the correct directory, I get this error:

D:\WebProgramlama\ShopApp\ShopApp.WebUI>dotnet ef migrations add yy

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationIdentityDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Comment: I try your code and migration successfully with PMC,please ensure that the `ApplicationIdentityDbContext` is included in your migration path.

Comment: I am sure ApplicationIdentityDbContext  is included , Also,ApplicationIdentityDbContext  in web layer .I am doing right clicked to web layer  then I am choosing open folder in file explorer ,then i am writing migration .

Comment: I think it may be that the location of your context is incorrect. If we use the template generated by default, the context will be in the Data folder instead of Identity.

Comment: I handle it , probably reasons of error is that I was using some packages of old versions , thaks for helpfull comments

Comment: **ApplicationIdentityDbContext** ... {} is useless and can break migrations DI.